# VSCode error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, javafx

I've been trying to set up on JavaFX in VSCode. I added the JavaFX jar files to the referenced libraries and added the following statement to `launch.json` (obviously with my path to the lib folder):

```json
"vmArgs": "--module-path \"C:/path/to/javafx-sdk-19/lib\" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml"
```

This is exactly what multiple youtube videos and other StackOverflow posts have said to do, but I still keep getting this error.

(I know that I can use Maven or Gradle in VScode but am completely unfamiliar with both and still want to try to make this work.)

Hopefully I didn't miss anything painfully obvious but thank you for any help.

Comment: The easiest way to get JavaFX working (afaik) is [Liberica](https://bell-sw.com/pages/downloads/#/java-19-current). They include a fully working version with the full install. No additional setup or config required with that JDK.

Comment: How do you create the project? Did following this [tutorial](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#IDE-VSCode) help?

Comment: Does Windows require you to quote the module path itself? It's not quoted in the [tutorial](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/images/ide/vscode/ide/vscode07.png).

Comment: @trashgod Windows requires quotes around the path if the path has spaces in it.  I don't use vscode, but have seen previous questions to that effect on StackOverflow.  It does not matter in this case as the path has no spaces in it, but it doesn't hurt to quote the path either as long as it is done right.  IMO, the tutorial should be updated to provide info on quoting the path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You should download JavaFX for your JDK version.
2. Uncompress JavaFX.zip and move bin folder to your project.
3. You should create two classes, one for writing the JavaFX window code and one for running it.

The error can be fixed.

I suggest you learn how to use Maven or Gradle in vscode. It is very important.

Answer (score 2):

At runtime, your app needs access to the JavaFX ([OpenJFX](https://openjfx.io/)) libraries.

Either:

- Install a copy of the OpenJFX libraries with your app, as directed in the [Answer by RedSnack-BCS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74119318/642706).
- Replace your Java implementation with one that includes the OpenJFX libraries.

I know of two such implementations of Java (JDKs) that include necessary libraries:

- *ZuluFX*, a special edition of their Zulu product, by [Azul Systems](https://www.azul.com/).
- *LibericaFX*, a special edition of their Liberica product, by [BellSoft](https://bell-sw.com/).

---

You may have identified a third approach with the use of passing arguments to the JVM. But I am not familiar with that solution.